# Use sprite image for list

Tags: html, css

I am struggling a bit here: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/JBuE6/27/

I am trying to have a vertical list where each list item has it's own icon, where is loaded in a single sprite. I seem to have got some of the way where the image is displayed in the background.

How do I crop the sprite image to show correctly, and how do I offset them to show different images?

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="navimg" id="user"><a href="url">User</a></li>
    <li class="navimg" id="vacancy"><a href="url">Vacancies</a></li>
    <li class="navimg" id="company"><a href="url">Company</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.navimg { background:url('http://www.otlayi.com/web_images/content/free-doc-type-sprite-icons.jpg'); }
#user { left:30px }
#vacancies { left:60px }
#company { left:90px }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this.

http://jsfiddle.net/itsakt/V6EwJ/1/

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <i class="navimg" id="user"></i>
    <a href="url">User</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="navimg" id="vacancy"></i>
    <a href="url">Vacancies</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="navimg" id="company"></i>
    <a href="url">Company</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.navimg {
    background:url('http://www.otlayi.com/web_images/content/free-doc-type-sprite-icons.jpg'); 
    display:inline-block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}

#user {
    background-position:-10px -10px;
}

#vacancy { 
    background-position:-50px -10px;
}

#company { 
    background-position:-50px -40px;
}
```

I have changed the HTML and CSS which you mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the sprites stored in the same file, ordered on a row or a column, you can use background-position with pixel values to switch to the desired image on a certain event.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

```
.navimg { 
       background-image:url(***);
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

Then, adjust the background with `background-position;` Also, don't forget to set width and height to `<li>`

Here are some help articles:http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/
http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: I think this is a bit closer but still stuck: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/JBuE6/31/

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with `background-position` when you are using image sprites. Just made a quick mockup using your fiddle:

```
.navimg {
    background:url('http://www.otlayi.com/web_images/content/free-doc-type-sprite-icons.jpg');
    width: 0;
    height: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

#user {
    background-position: -10px -6px;
}

#vacancy {
    background-position: -48px -6px;
}

#company {
    background-position: -88px -6px;
}
```

[Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/JBuE6/37/)